nodejs how to update cookie without change the maxage time?
I have a nodejs backend and react frontend. I can send successfull back to my react a cookie. But if I update it maybe I use refresh token then I overwrite the cookie but the problem is the maxage are removed. From expiration 2600 it goes to "session".
export const refresh = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    console.log('REFRESH TOKEN');
    console.log(req.body);
    
    const result = await supabase.auth.refreshSession({refresh_token: req.body.refresh_token});
    const data = result.data;

    console.log('HI');
  
    if(!data.user || !data.session) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(result.error)
      throw new ErrorException(500, 'Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.');
    }

    const userInfo = {
    user: {
      id: data.user.id,
      email: data.user.email,
      app_metadata: data.user.app_metadata,
      user_metadata: data.user.user_metadata,
    },
    session: {
      access_token: data.session.access_token,
      expires_in: data.session.expires_in,
      expires_at: data.session.expires_at,
      refresh_token: data.session.refresh_token
    }}

    res.cookie('user', userInfo.user);
    res.cookie('jwt' , userInfo.session);
    res.status(200).json(userInfo);

